# Combat casualties

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Got board game, what happens if someone attacks a territory held by another player, and wins but after combat has no troops to move cause of casualties? Does that player have to put power tokens in both lands?

Answer (score 1):

Attacking units move into the target province prior to battle.

If you moved all your troops,  you would have to have left a power token in the original province if you wanted to maintain control.

If,  for whatever reason,  after the battle there are no troops left in the province, it remains unclaimed unless the defender already had a power token there.